# Total pack overvoltage threshold

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, bms

I have set following BMS parameters. My BMS cutoff voltage is set to 66.8 V. CV mode starts at 66.8V.

The OV threshold should be set to 4.2V according to cell upper cutoff voltage.

However the supplier states that I should increase the threshold to 4.23V equivalent to TOV threshold to 67.68V, my balancing would be much better as CV mode timing is increased.

Is this approach correct?

[image: BMS parameters]